# Tree replanting question

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, planting, transplanting

I have a generic question.

Can all trees be replanted, by extracting them with all their roots, and, I would guess, also the soil, or are there also some trees that cannot be moved?

What are some factors and techniques used to replant?

Is this something one would learn through forestry courses?

Any insights, into this, works be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

In theory any trees can be transplanted as long as the root is not damaged, and you minimise the shock that the tree experiences.

Some trees are harder to transplant if they have deep tp roots.  Similarly, it is easier to transplant trees with fibrous roots.

A forestry course will only teach you about trees used for forestry.